# Form POST being sent with no parameters

Tags: javascript, html, http

I have a very simple HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function post() {   
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("method", "post");
            form.setAttribute("action", "/agree");

            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "location");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "URL goes here");

            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="button" value="I agree" onclick="post()">

</body>
```

For whatever reason, both in the Firefox network inspector and in the HTTPServlet code handling the post, there are no parameters, e.g. in the network inspector it says "No parameters for this request", and in Java using getParameter or getParameterNames both return null.

I have tried changing the form of the JS a little bit, to see another format I often see being used for adding attributes. For example:

```
hiddenField.type = "hidden";
```

But this changes nothing (what's the difference anyway?). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to append the `hiddenField` to the form:

```
form.appendChild(hiddenField);
```

Small side note: there is missing a double quote here (before `/agree`):

```
form.setAttribute("action", "/agree");
```

Comment: Well that would do it. Thanks!

Comment: @elykl33t: need more help? If the answer was sufficient, please don't forget to accept the answer.